# Joomla custom grid frontpage articles

Tags: css, joomla

in my current joomla template I have an option to display featured articles in 2by 2 or 3by3 columns, but I would like to have a custom layout, do you guys know any plugin/extension that could help me to do that faster? Here is an image of the result that I need:

[image: layout]

The middle row is what joomla is by default in all rows, but I want to customize the first and last row as you can see in the image.

Thank you

Comment: I have installed a few modules but none gives the option to "break" the grid pattern like I need.

Comment: By defaul joomla breaks the display into 3 regions ("leading" -- full width number specified when you create the menu link), intro (multicolumn, you specify the number of columns and rows when you make the menu link) and links (links only, in column, number specified when you make hte link). You can just make an override to do what you want instead i..e have three sections of intro instead of two. It's mainly just math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use k2 CCK for that. It allows you to split the content into 4 sections. Each section has variable amount of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than installing k2 cck for this (unless you actually need k2 cck), do like @elin suggested and override the featured view ([like here](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)). You can adjust the layout as suggested below:

- Copy /components/com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default.php to /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/featured/default.php.

In the section of the file that loops through the introtext-articles, around line 52, replace this:

```
$key = ($key - $leadingcount) + 1;
$rowcount = (((int) $key - 1) % (int) $this->columns) + 1;
$row = $counter / $this->columns;
```

with this:

```
$key = ($key - $leadingcount) + 1;
$columns=$this->columns; 
if($counter<3)  $columns=3;
$rowcount = (((int) $key - 1) % (int) $columns) + 1;
$row = $counter / $columns;
```

- Also replace later occurences of $this->columns with $columns
- In the menu-setup, set leading count to 2, introtext-count to 5, columns to 2.

Your template should now display something similar to what you need, with the second row contained in a div with class="items-row cols-3 row-1", and the third row with class="items-row cols-2 row-2". You might have to adjust your css to get the correct result.